# Can I call function in python with named arguments as a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

For example

```
username_type = 'email'

def get_user_by(email=None, username=None):
    if email:
        return user.get_by_email(email)
    elif username:
        return user.get_by_username(username)

get_user_by(username_type = username)
```

Of course this line won't work
`get_user_by(username_type = username)`
But I want something like this to make it work

I don't know which type will I get the user from but I want the named argument based on variable

Comment: `get_user_by(**{username_type: username})`

Comment: Why have two hard-coded parameters if only one will ever be used? `def get_user_by(type, value): if type == 'email': return user.get_by_email(value) else ...` Then you'll just call `get_user_by(type=username_type, username)`.

Comment: @chepner i'll use it in sqlalchemy filter so i want a shorthand to query the user i don't want to type table.query.filter_by(email=username).first() many times

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a dictionary of keywords arguments to a function using the `**` operator. The keys of the dictionary are the parameter names in the function.

In this case, that could be:

```
get_user_by(**{username_type: username})
```

If the variable `username_type` has the value `'email'` then the username would be received in `get_user_by` as the keyword argument `email`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP could use a little more detail. The * and ** notation are used to pack and unpack in python, * to pack and unpack a list and ** to pack and unpack a dictionary. For example,

```
[1,2,3,*[4,5,6]]               #The inside list will be unpacked into the overall list. 
{'a':1,'b':2, **dict(z=7,w=8)} #The dictionary will be unpacked into the outside dictionary.
```

This also works with function calls and definitions.

```
def f(*args): #pack all args into a list called args. 
    return args
print(f(1,2,3))
y = [1,2,3]
f(*y)        #Unpack y into f, same as f(1,2,3)

def f(**kargs): #pack all keyword-args into a dictionary called kargs. 
    return kargs.get('thing',None)
print(f(x=7))
print(f(thing=7))
```

Answer (score 0):

If one needs a more generalized solution, both for positional and named arguments, one should replace the line

```
get_user_by(username_type = username)
```

with a decorator-like code:

```
def args_passer(args, kwargs):
    def out():
        return get_user_by(*args, **kwargs)
    return out()
args_passer([], {username_type: username})
```